# WCF Services across servers

Tags: c#, wcf

Ok guys. This is more of a "Can this be done?" question as opposed to "How do you do this?"

I have a WCF project with multiple services and everything is lining up fine. Two of them will be wrapped in Windows Service installers that will go on two different servers. Is it possible to call a method in one service from the other service if they are on two separate machines? Or do I have to use the Callback scenario I have seen used before?

I appreciate any advice or ideas. Thanks.

Comment: That's kind of the whole point of WCF....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the binding you are using and any firewall / network route rules on and between the two machines.

If you are using a namedPipeBinding, the answer is no because named pipes are bound to a machine. However, if you are using any of the other bindings like webHttp, basicHttp, etc you should be ok.  The beauty of WCF is that you should be able to just spin up another service endpoint using a different binding if necessary -- so even if you are using named pipes, it should be pretty straight forward to swap that out with a different binding.

A WCF service can certainly be a client to another WCF service.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you ... 

That's what I thought. The old code is using DuplexChannelFactory and it occurred to me that I could just call the Service directly without creating a channel. I believe our binding is basicHttp but I will have to double check to be sure.

Comment: In the caller service I am doing something like this: OtherService foo = new OtherService(); ... foo.CallMethod(); So according to what you are saying, if the binding is simple enough, I should be able to do that across servers. Fantastic! Makes this code upgrade a whole lot easier! :-D

Comment: That should work exactly the same.  You should not have any issues with it, provided that the machines can see each other and that the firewall allows inbound/outbound connections on whatever ports you are using.

Comment: Ok .. so here is the problem. I have one WCF service on one server trying to connect to another WCF service that is on multiple servers. What we are trying to do is have multiple boxes processing at the same time. How can one WCF service talk to multiple boxes? In other words, how does the calling service differentiate between the different servers? 

To date, I have wrapped the service being called in a Windows Service Wrapper, used DuplexChannelFactory AND ChannelFactory without any effect. Telnet will also not see the open port we have on the downstream box.

Any suggestions?